# Cookies. Append many values in cookies with javascript

Tags: javascript, razor

I'm sorry for my question, but I don't find any answer.

Is it possible append many values in a single cookie ?

My aim is to create a cookie called ALLINFO, and append in it values such as

name, surname, age, phone etc.

Is it possibile ? Some example please ?

Thank you in advance.

p.s. I work in vs2013 with mvc

Comment: "Is it possible append many values in a single cookie ?" Yes Or you can store multiple cookies.... personally I would use localstorage and not cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a object in the cookie

```
(function(){
    var o = JSON.parse('{"name":"hello","surname":"kc"}');
    var e = 'Thu Nov 10 2020 15:44:38';
    document.cookie = 'ALLINFO='+ JSON.stringify(o) +';expires=' + e;
 })()
```

For reading the cookie

you can do

```
function read_cookie(name) {
 var result = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name + '=([^;]+)'));
 result && (result = JSON.parse(result[1]));
 return result;
}
read_cookie('ALLINFO')
```